# mysql connection in Zend framework2

Tags: database, zend-framework

This is my application.ini database configuration:

```
  resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
  resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
  resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
  resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
  resources.db.params.username = "user"
  resources.db.params.password = "password"
  resources.db.params.dbname = "test"
```

I have set all informations are correct, but still now i'm getting an error like 
  `Error: 593: Authentication failed. Password is missing.`

I don't know "how to resolve it?". If anybody met this kind of error, Please help to save me guys!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure your username is `user` and password `password` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your problem is..normally it will work with your settings anyway check this

In your bootstrap.php add this piece of code

```
protected function _initDBCheck(){
    $config = new Zend_Config(
        array(
            'database' => array(
                'adapter' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
                'params'  => array(
                    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
                    'dbname'   => 'test',
                    'username' => 'user',
                    'password' => 'password',
                )
            )
        )
    );

    try{
    $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);
    }catch(Exception $e){
      echo $e;die(); //this will show any error
   }


}
```

Comment: sorry for asking this question. Actually i'm newbie to zend framework. Where to place this code?

Comment: There is a `bootstrap` file normally it will be in `application/Bootstrap.php`

Comment: Thank you @ubercooluk.Now also it displays the same error. It happen only for info table, other tables are working fine

Comment: check whats the storage engine of the info table (MyIsam or InnoDB)..change it according to the other tables

Comment: Sorry for late reply. All table's storage engine is InnoDB, 'info' table storage engine is also InnoDB